# Find the probability that two randomly selected subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ have exactly 2 elements common in their intersection

Tags: probability

Clearly, the total number of subsets possible is $2^5$

For two elements to be common, both subsets need to have at least two elements, so we can form quite a lot of cases which satisfy both conditions.

Now there are far too many cases (IMO) for me to manually curate, so is their a shorter way, complementary probability perhaps?

Even in complimentary method there seem to be a lot of subsets, but here is what I got

$$\binom 51(\binom 41 +\binom 42 +\binom 43 +\binom 44) + \binom 52 (\binom 31 + \binom 32 +\binom 33).....+\binom 54 (\binom 11)$$
$$=5(2^4-1) +10 (2^3-1) +10(2^2-1) +5 (2-1)$$
$$=180$$

Which comes out to be greater than $2^5$, which isn’t possible. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: My reasoning

I found the cases where one set has an element, and then the other set does not have that element, although I now realise I missed the cases where they have 1 element common or 3 or 4 or 5, which effectively makes my attempt useless.

Comment: Assuming sets may repeat, a better approach to counting this... first, choose the two elements who are shared in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways.  Then, for each remaining element, pick if it appears in set $A$, appears in set $B$ or appears in neither.  This gives a total of $\binom{5}{2}\times 3^3 = 270$.  Now... note that this is greater than $2^5$ as you complained about for your answer... but recognize that *this doesn't matter!*  Our sample space was actually the number of ways of *picking two subsets* which is ($2^{5})^2$, not $2^5$.

Comment: As for your attempt, I do not understand your logic in constructing your expression and so can not comment on what makes it incorrect.

Comment: @JMoravitz I added my reasoning

Comment: Your reasoning also ignored $\emptyset$ for some reason... $\emptyset$ is a perfectly valid subset to have been randomly selected as either $A$ or $B$.

Comment: @JMoravitz How did you get $3^3$?

Comment: "*Then for each remaining element, pick if it appears in set $A$, appears in set $B$ or appears in neither...*"  so after picking the two shared elements for each of the three remaining elements we have three choices.  Applying multiplication principle (*rule of product*) with $3$ choices for the first (*in $A$, in $B$, or in neither*) we multiply that by the number of choices for the next which is again $3$, and multiply that for the final which is yet again $3$, giving $3\times 3\times 3$.  Along with the $\binom{5}{2}$ choices for what the two shared elements were gives the overall

Comment: @JMoravitz what do you mean by $\phi$?

Comment: The empty set...

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah I know. I meant to ask how is an empty set a valid case? Both sets need to have at least 2

Comment: Not in what you were counting in your attempt they don't. That's my point

Comment: I can not understand how the cardinality of sample space becomes $2^5 \times ^5$.  That means you are supposing $(A,B) $ and $(B,A)$ are different. Why they are different? Why does the order of picking matter ?@JMoravitz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: $2^5$ is the count of whether each element is in *a* subset or not.  **However**, you are selecting 2 such subsets.  So we must count whether each element is included in each subset: which is $4^5$ outcomes in the space.

For the favored case, we wish a selection of 2 from the five elements to be in both, and each of the remaining 3 elements have but 3 options (in one, in the other, or in neither).  So that is $\binom 52 3^3$ favored outcomes.

As all outcomes are unbiased, the probability is: $$\dbinom 5 2\cdot \dfrac{3^3}{4^5} =\dfrac{135}{512}$$

Comment: If we had to select 3 subsets, would it be $2^{15}$?

Comment: @Aditya With three subsets, each among the five elements would hava $2^3$ options, so, yes, that would be a space of $2^{15}$ outcomes

Answer (score 4):

There are $\binom52=10$ two-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and every pair $\langle A,B\rangle$ of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ whose intersection has exactly $2$ elements has one of them as its intersection. $A\cap B=S$ if and only if $A\setminus S$ and $B\setminus S$ are disjoint subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus S$, so to count the pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ such that $A\cap B=S$, we need to count the pairs of disjoint subsets of a $3$-element set.

The number of pairs $\langle C,D\rangle$ of disjoint subsets of a set $X$ of $n$ elements can be computed as follows. For $k=0,\ldots,n$ there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose $C$ of cardinality $k$, and there are then $2^{n-k}$ ways to choose $D$ disjoint from $C$, so by the binomial theorem there are altogether

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k1^k\cdot2^{n-k}=(1+2)^n=3^n$$

such pairs.

> Alternatively, and even more simply, each of the $n$ elements of $X$ can be assigned arbitrarily to $C$, $D$, or $X\setminus(C\cup D)$, and this assignment can be made in $3^n$ ways.

In our case $|X|=|\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus S|=3$, so there are $3^3=27$ pairs of disjoint subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus S$. Thus, there are $10\cdot27=270$ ordered pairs of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that have $2$-element intersections. If you want unordered pairs, you need only cut this number in half.

Comment: Can you please tell me why the number of elements in the sample space is $2^5 \times 2^5$ ? Why ? It should have been $2^5 \choose 2$ and if we allow two chosen subsets to be identical , it will be $2^5 \choose 2$$+2^5$.@Brian M. Scott

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I did indeed; thanks.

Comment: @sani: Because I’m counting **ordered** pairs of subsets of $X$.

Comment: Why you are counting ordered pairs ? Why order of picking the sets matter ? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @sani: The statement of the problem is ambiguous: nothing in the problem indicates whether the order matters.  I chose one possible interpretation and clearly indicated which interpretation I was using. If the order does *not* matter, obviously an adjustment must be made.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you verify whether my answer to this question is correct or not, because @ sani feels that there is a mistake in it, however I think it is correct and indeed my answer matches with the accepted answer.

Comment: @HarryPotter: It’s correct, and I just upvoted it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks sir :-) .

Comment: @HarryPotter: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say instead of choosing two subsets from a single set, we choose subsets from the two sets $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, so number of subsets that can be chosen from $A$ are $2^{5}$ and similarly total number of subsets chosen from $B$ are $2^5$.

So, in a total of $2^5 \cdot 2^5=2^{10}$ ways, we can choose the subsets from $A$ and $B$.

Now, we need to find the cases, where there are exactly $2$ elements common to them.

If there are two elements in subset choosen from $A$, which can be done in $\displaystyle \binom{5}{2}$ ways, for two elements to be common, we can choose subsets in $B$ in $\displaystyle \binom{2}{2}$ ways, and for the rest of $3$ the elements, they can be chosen in $2^3$ ways.

If there are three elements in subset choosen from $A$, which can be done in $\displaystyle \binom{5}{3}$ ways, so choose $2$ elements from those three choosen for $A$, that is, $\displaystyle\binom{3}{2}$ and for rest choose them in $2^2$ ways.

If there four elements in subset choosen from $A$, there are $\displaystyle \binom{5}{4}$ ways. Choose two from those $4$, i.e $\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}$, choose rest in $2^1$ ways.

If all five elements are choosen in $A$, choose any two elements in $B$, for which there are $\displaystyle\binom{5}{2}$ ways.

So we have, probability that there is exactly one element common is

$$\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{2}{2}2^3+\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{2}2^2+\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{2}2^1+\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{2}2^0}{2^{10}}=\dfrac{135}{512}$$

Comment: Can you please tell me why the number of elements in the sample space is $2^5 \times 2^5$ ? Why ? It should have been $2^5 \choose 2$ and if we allow two chosen subsets to be identical , it will be $2^5 \choose 2$$+2^5$.@Harry Potter

Comment: @sani What do you mean? Suppose there are 2 elements in one set and 2 elements in another set, and we have to choose 1 element from each set, so what would be the number of ways of doing that? would it be $\binom{2}{2}$ or $2\times 2$ ?

Comment: No no this is not the correct way to choose. You have to pick $2$ elements from a set containing $2^n$ elements. @Harry Potter

Comment: let's suppose you have chosen two subsets $A,B$ from the set $\{1 ,2 , 3, 4 , 5\}$. If the number of elements of sample space is $2^5 \times 2^5$ , then the order of picking the sets $A,B$ do matter.  That means $A ,B$ is different from $B,A$. But why they will be different ?@Harry Potter

Comment: @sani First clear your doubts before downvoting. My answer matches with the other answers given.  We don't have to choose elements from a set, we have to choose subsets from a given set. And instead of choosing two subsets from a set, I am choosing a subset from $A$ and another subset from $B$ which is identical to $A$. Now I am case wise counting according to the number of elements in the subset choosen from $A$.

Comment: You have assumed a wrong thing. You have to choose 2 elements from the power set of the given set. It should be $2^5 \choose 2$.@Harry Potter

Comment: @sani There are $2^5$ subsets of $A$. Same with $B$. In how many ways can we choose subsets from $A$? Well, we could choose it in $2^5$ ways as we can choose anything. Same with $B$. So, in total, in how many ways can we choose subsets from $A$ and $B$? If you still find flaw, you are welcomed to post your own solution and let's see what answer you get.