# The probability that two randomly selected subsets of the set $\{1 , 2, 3, 4 , 5\}$ have exactly two elements in their intersection , is

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

The probability that two randomly selected subsets of the set $\{1 , 2, 3, 4 , 5\}$ have exactly two elements in their intersection is $\frac{135}{2^9}$.

In this problem [Find the probability that two randomly selected subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ have exactly 2 elements common in their intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046685/find-the-probability-that-two-randomly-selected-subsets-of-1-2-3-4-5-have) , it is said that the sample space has $2^{10}$ elements.

I can not understand how sample space contains $2^{5}\times 2^5$ elements. It should have $2^5 \choose 2$ elements. It has $\binom{2^5}{2} + 2^5$ elements if we allow two chosen subsets being identical.

Comment: This is simply a binomial probability problem with $n=5$ and $p=\frac14$. The probability that a given number is in both sets is $p=\frac14$. The probabilitgy of exactly two successes is $\binom52(\frac14)^2(\frac34)^3$.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**  Let's say the sets are $A$ and $B$.  You have four choices for each of the five elements in the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$: place an element in both sets $A$ and $B$, place it only in set $A$, place it only in set $B$, or place it in neither subset.  Hence, the sample space has $4^5$ elements.

**Method 2:** There are $2^5$ ways to select set $A$ since we can choose to include or not include each element of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ in set $A$.  For each such choice, there are $2^5$ ways to select subset $B$.  Since the choice of sets $A$ and $B$ is independent, there are $2^5 \cdot 2^5 = 2^{10}$ ways to choose the two subsets of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

*What is wrong with your approach?*

While you did not explain your reasoning, it appears that the term
$$\binom{2^5}{2}$$
is supposed to count the number of ways of choosing two different subsets of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, while $2^5$ is supposed to count the number of ways of choosing two identical subsets.

**Method 3:** There are $2^5$ ways of choosing the subset $A$ and one way to select set $B$ so that it is the same as set $A$.  Thus, the term $2^5$ makes sense.

For each of the $2^5$ ways we can select set $A$, there are $2^5 - 1$ ways to select set $B$ such that set $B$ is different from set $A$.  Hence, there are $2^5(2^5 - 1)$ ways to pick two different subsets.

Thus, we again obtain
$$2^5 + 2^5(2^5 - 1) = 2^5 + 2^{10} - 2^5 = 2^{10}$$
elements in the sample space.

**Note:**  The problem with using $\binom{2^5}{2}$ for the number of ways of selecting two different subsets is that there are two orders in which we could pick the same pair of distinct subsets.  Notice that
$$2\binom{2^5}{2} + 2^5 = 2 \cdot \binom{32}{2} + 2^5 = 2 \cdot \frac{32 \cdot 31}{2} + 32 = 32 \cdot 31 + 32 = 992 + 32 = 1024 = 2^{10}$$

Comment: How many ways you can select $2$ objects from $n$ distinct objects ? it is simply $n\choose 2$. I do not know why you are doing $n \times n$.

Comment: Here  we have $2^n$ elements in the power set of the gven set. WE can choose $2$ elements from them in $2^n \choose 2$ ways. @N F. Taussing

Comment: I do  not know why you are making so much complicated.@N F.Taussing

Comment: Now we have to add $2^5$ with $2^5 \choose 2$  to get the number of the elements of the set $\{ $(A,B) : A ,B  are subsets of the set $\{1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 \}$ and the pairs $(A , B)$ and $(B,A)$ are non-distinguishable.$\}$. And  this set is the sample space of the random experiment.@N F. Taussing

Comment: In your approach , the pairs $(A,B) $ and $(B,A)$ are distinguishable. why they are distinguishable ? why the order of picking the subsets matter ?@N F. Taussing

Comment: Your method is totally beyond my understanding.@N F. Taussing

Comment: @sani: Take 2 "regular" playing dice (6 sided, labeled with numbers 1-6, fair), throw them and record their sum. 7 will  come up most often, then probability get lower to the extreme sides of sum 2 and sum 12. Especially record how often you get sums 11 and 12. 

If you do this long enough, you'll find that sum 11 comes up roughly double as often as sum 12. That should suprise you, because with the way you chose events, there is exactly one way to get sum 12, namely as $6+6$ from the pair $(6.6)$ and also exactly one way to get sum 11, namely as $5+6$ from the (unordered) pair $(5,6)$.

Comment: This example shows why in most situations, where the random events (dice throws) are independent of each other, it actually matters that you consider them as different and ordered, even if the operation you want to do with them does not care about order. 

Because if one dice happens to be red as base color and the other is green, there is still only one way to get sum 12: The red and green dice must show a 6. But now there are 2 ways to get sum 11. red shows 5 and green shows 6, and vice versa. That is why your counting method is different and in the dice example incorrect.

Comment: But I can not understand why we will try to keep the probability of getting the sum $11$ and $7$ same ?@Ingix

Comment: What is the problem if $7$ comes most often and the probability of getting $11$ is very less ? Where is the problem ? Why will we try to make their probability of getting equal ?@Ingix

Comment: I am still waiting for your reply.@Ingix

Comment: @Sani By taking the order of selection into account, we ensure that each outcome in the sample space is equally likely to occur.  If $A \neq B$, there are two orders in which the set $\{A, B\}$ can be obtained, $(A, B)$ and $(B, A)$.  However, there is only one ordered pair $(A, A)$ in which subset $A$ is selected twice.  Thus, the set $\{A, B\}$ is twice as likely to occur as $\{A, A\}$.  Treating the selections as ordered pairs accounts for this, while your method does not.

Comment: Thank You So much. I have finally understood my mistake. Thank you @N F. Taussing.

Comment: If two picks are independent , then number of elements in the sample space will be $2^{10}$. If two 2nd pick is dependent on the first pick , number of elements in the sample space will be $2^5 \choose 2$.@N F. Taussing

Comment: Thank you so much for spending so much time to make me understand. I do not have anyone to ask doubt. I have no words to thank this site. I have got so much help from this website.@N F. Taussing

Comment: I am disturbing one last time. Can you please suggest me a good Probability book where I can go from basic to college level ? @N F. Taussing

Comment: Even the most basic books on probability are written for college students.  The texts [Introduction to Probability](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486675491/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=John+E.+Freund&qid=1629276722&sr=8-2) by John E. Freund and [Probability:  An Introduction](https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Introduction-Samuel-Goldberg/dp/0486652521/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=Samuel+Goldberg&qid=1629276772&sr=8-4) deal with finite sample spaces, so they do not require the use of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Because the subsets, let's say $A$ and $B$, can be the same we must treat them as distinguishable. Hence $A$ has $2^5$ choices and $B$ has $2^5$ choices for a total of $2^{10}$ ways to pick $A$ and $B$.

If we use your result of $\binom{2^5}{2}+2^5$, you are saying that each of the cases when $A$ and $B$ are identical has twice the probability of occurring when compared to a case when $A$ and $B$ are distinct. This is clearly not the case as each possible ordered pair $A,B$ should have the same probability of occurring.

Comment: I did not get you.@Alan Abraham

Comment: if you have $n$ numbered balls , how many ways will you select $2$ balls ?@Alan Abraham

Comment: @sani You can select $2$ balls in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways... I'm not sure why you are asking that. What part did you not get?

Comment: Here you have $2^5$ elements. You have to choose $2$ elements from them. How can you choose in $2^5 \times 2^5$ ways ?@Alan Abraham

Comment: I see your point now. Your argument only works when the $2$ elements must be distinct. I believe the question could be more clear in that the $2$ subsets must be distinct. Indeed, this question is somewhat ambiguous and should have been cleared up.

Comment: okay if you allow them to be identical then you can add $2^5$@Alan Abraham

Comment: When you are saying $2^5 \times 2^5$ is the number of ways to choose two subsets  then you are saying $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ are different. If we choose $A ,B$ then how it is different from choosing $B,A$ ?I can not understand.@Alan Abraham

Comment: The disagreement between sani and Alan Abraham is what exactly "two randomly selected subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$" means. To me an Alan it means: "Chose any of the $2^5$ subsets, with equal probability, for $A$, then, independently, choose any of the $2^5$ subsets, with equal probability, for $B$." For sani it seems to be "Choose, with equal probability, a subset pair $(A,B)$ from the union of 2 sets. The first is the set of unordered pairs of subsets $(A,B)$ where $A \neq B$, containing ${2^5 \choose 2}$ elements. The second set are the $2^5$ subset pairs of the form $(A,A)$.

Comment: Both are possible interpretations. I just think that Alan's and mine is likely the intended one for the problem. In my experience, if there is a process where this problem comes up, it is likely that the selection of $A$ and $B$ are independent, which they are **not** in sani's. As Alan pointed out, it makes equal pairs happen more often.

Comment: I can not understand your last comment's last line. Can any one please elaborate ? @Ingix

Comment: Let's go from the subsets of a 5 element set to the subsets of a 1 element set, to make the examples smaller. There are only 2 such subsets, of course, let's call them $E$ (empty) and $F$ (full). Then Alan's approach says there are 4 possible and equally probably results for the pairs of subsets: $(E,E), (E,F), (F,E), (F,F)$.
You say there are 3 such pairs of equally probable results: $(E,F), (E,E), (F,F)$.
This is "missing" the "mixed" pair $(F,E)$, which is another way of saying it makes the "equal" pairs more likely.

Comment: @sani See above. If you are coming from a combinatorics point of view, and recognize that the condition about the intersection is symmetric regarding the 2 subsets, then it totally makes sense to count as you did. The problem is that when calculating probabilities using the classical "good case divided by all cases" formula, it is imperative that all the cases considered have equal probability. That is something that combinatorics can't decide, that has to come from the way something is chosen. That wasn't specified in the problem. The disagreement comes from different way to do that choosing.

Comment: $\{(A ,B): A,B $ are subsets of the set $\{1 , 2, 3 , 4 , 5\}$ and the pairs $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ are non-distinguishable $\}$. In my understanding , this is the sample space of the random experiment. @Ingix