# What is the probability that two random subsets of a superset have no intersection?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $$ S={1,2,...,n} $$ From the power set, $ P(S) $, of $S$, two subsets $A$, $B$
are chosen at random. If each subset is equally likely to be chosen, then, the probability that the sets $ A $ and $ B $ have no elements in common is....

Here are some of my tries:

Probability that two particular sets will be chosen is $ 2^{-2n} $.  If from one set $\phi$ is chosen, no intersection, is guaranteed, if a Singelton is chosen from first set then

1. if $ \phi $ is chosen from second set, then no intersection is
   guaranteed
2. if some set with cardinality = 1 is chosen from second set then no intersection guaranteed for all $n$ sets except for 1 which is the same as first set.
3. if some set with cardinality = 2 is chosen from second set then for no intersection guaranteed for all $^{n}C _2 $sets except for $n-1$ which contain the singleton in first set.
4. if some set with cardinality = 3 is chosen from second set then for no intersection guaranteed for all $^ {n}C _2 $ sets except for???? I can't think further.  I can't figure out a general term for $n$ cardinality.

So far, I have figured.

$ P(A\bigcap B = \phi) =  2^{-2n} [^{n}C_0 * 1 + ^{n}C_1(^{n}C_0 * 1 + ^{n}C_1 -1 + ^{n}C_2 -(n-1) ..... ) + ^{n}C_2(....) .......^{n}C_n(....) ] $

I have tried finding complement of the question (finding probability that they have at least something in common)

I have tried using de Morgans law,  $ P(A\bigcap B = \phi) =  P((A^c \bigcup B^c)^c) = \phi) $ but I can't figure it out.

I created a python program to find probability however computer cant calculate probabilities for $n >= 25$ and the result does not seem to have converged. At $ n = 25 $, probability is around $0.001$.

I have looked at other similar questions however they don't deal with subsets of superset but  some simple subset of simple sets.

[The probability that two randomly selected subsets of the set $\{1 , 2, 3, 4 , 5\}$ have exactly two elements in their intersection , is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226303/the-probability-that-two-randomly-selected-subsets-of-the-set-1-2-3-4-5)

Comment: Your program's results don't seem to converge to $0$ for large $n$?

Comment: **Hint.** Encode each subset as a binary string of length $n$. Then the $k$th element in the superset is present in the intersection of the subsets, if the strings both have what in the $k$th position?

Comment: Hint: two sets have empty intersection if and only if, for every $j\in S$, at most one of $A$ and $B$ contains $j$ ... and these events are independent for different $j$. (By the way, one should specify that $A$ and $B$ are chosen independently as well as uniformly.)

Comment: This is _bound_ to be a duplicate.

Comment: In some sense a choice of probability measure is required. There is not a unique probability distribution that can be defined over such an event space.

Answer (score 31):

Construct the sets $A$ and $B$ by following this procedure: for each element of $S$, flip a fair coin to decide if it is a member of $A$, and flip again to decide, independently, if it is to  be a member of $B$. The chance the element in question is not in $A\cap B$ is $3/4$, and the chance that none of the $n$ elements of $S$ are in $A\cap B$ is thus $(3/4)^n$.

Comment: This is a special case of using indicator functions. It might be nice to say a word about those if you know them. They are very useful for all kinds of probability problems.

Answer (score 9):

Number of pairs is $2^{2n}$, and for the number of pairs $(A,B): A \cap B=\emptyset $, you just notice that, to obtain such a pair $(A,B)$, it’s the same as constructing a mapping from $S$ to $\{ x,y,z\}$ (mapping elements of $A$ to $x$, elements of $B$ to $y$, elements of the complement to $z$). So $3^{n}$ many.

Answer (score 5):

Pick a subset $S_1 \subset S$, and suppose $\#S_1 = m$ is the number of elements in $S_1$. There are $n - m$ elements in $S\setminus S_1$, hence the probability of choosing a subset of $S_2 \subset S$ disjoint to $S_1$ is
$$P(S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset | \#S_1 = m) = \frac{2^{n-m}}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^{m}}.$$
Summing over all $m$-element subsets of $S$ yields
$$P(S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^m\binom{n}{m} = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n,$$
the final equality by the binomial theorem.

EDIT: It also depends on if "order matters." As noted by other commenters, there are $3^n$ tuples of disjoint subsets. However, order matters in these tuples, that is if $A\cap B = \emptyset$ then the pair of disjoint subsets $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ are considered distinct ways to pick the subsets. This may not be desirable behavior. In that event, clearly the solution $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ is allowed, hence there are $3^n - 1$ disjoint tuples where we double count; halving that number and adding back the solution $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ yields $$\frac{3^n-1}{2}+1 = \frac{3^n+1}{2}$$ tuples of disjoint subsets of $S$ where order does not matter. There are
$$2^n + \binom{2^n}{2} = 2^{2n-1} + 2^{n-1}$$ tuples of the form $\{(a,a) : a\in 2^S\} \cup \{\{a,b\} : a,b\in 2^S\}$, since if we choose two subsets of $S$ at random we can pick the same subset twice or two distinct subsets. So in this interpretation the probability is
$$\frac{3^n+1}{4^n +2^n}.$$

Comment: For $n=1$, the other answers give $\frac34$ while yours gives $\frac23$. It is easy to check by elementary means that the other answers are right in this case.

Comment: As I mentioned it depends on how you wish to interpret the problem. For example, consider the singleton $\{1\}$ and its power set $\{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$. If order matters then indeed we have a 3/4 probability; $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ and $(\emptyset, \{1\})$ and $(\{1\}, \emptyset)$ are all disjoint, and there are $4$ total pairs to choose from. But if you consider $(\emptyset, \{1\})$ and $(\{1\}, \emptyset)$ to be the same tuple, then there is only a 2/3 probability, which was the intended consequence.

Comment: OK. I accept your argument that there was ambiguity in the question. One upvote for you (only),